# Capitalization of names that begin lowercased, at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: sentence, capitalization, proper-nouns, sentence-starts

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How Should Trademarks be Written?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2903/how-should-trademarks-be-written)
>   [How do you capitalize a proper noun such as “iPhone”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9063/how-do-you-capitalize-a-proper-noun-such-as-iphone)

Many products these days have names that intentionally begin with lowercase letters.  The most common examples are of the Apple "iDevice" variety, but there are some others - inSSIDer is one.

When beginning a sentence with these names, should the name be capitalized?

Comment: Even more probable duplicate of [How do you capitalize a proper noun such as "iPhone"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9063/how-do-you-capitalize-a-proper-noun-such-as-iphone)

Comment: I agree that this will (d)evolve into a duplicate of [How Should Trademarks be Written?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2903/how-should-trademarks-be-written)

Comment: I'm sorry.  The suggested exact duplicate didn't pop up when I wrote the title for this thread.

Comment: Looking for what reported when writing the title doesn't help much; the only way to verify if the question has been already asked is to search using the search field on this site, or to search with Google, writing "site:english.stackexchange.com " at the beginning of the search string (to notice the space after ".com").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if a company considers non-standard formatting of a trademark "official", style guides usually suggest that the formatting be ignored. But, trademarks beginning with a one-letter lowercase prefix pronounced as a separate letter do not need to be capitalized if the second letter is capitalized. Ultimately, the [Wikipedia Manual of Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aManual_of_Style_%28trademarks%29) suggests rephrasing to avoid beginning sentences with such trademarks.

Comment: Brilliant. That paragraph should look pretty familiar then. :)