# Capitalising a sentence whose first word is explicitly lowercase

Tags: sentence, capitalization, proper-nouns, programming, sentence-starts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capitalization of names that begin lowercased, at the beginning of a sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16027/capitalization-of-names-that-begin-lowercased-at-the-beginning-of-a-sentence)

Let's say that you have a word that should be typed with leading lowercase letter. Perhaps it's a computer command. Perhaps it's an Internet nickname. I can't find any more serious examples.

When you put that word at the beginning of a sentence, should you capitalise it?

> `cat` allows you to display contents
>   of a file.

The convention is that commands are typed in fixed-width font, so this doesn't stand out as much.

> soccer_boy_89 turned out to be my
>   sister's account.

This does, though.

Of course you could paraphrase the sentence such that the problematic word is not the first one, but that's not the point here.

Comment: Cases to consider where typography won't help you: eBay, iPod, amazon.com.

Comment: "Of course you could paraphrase the sentence such that the problematic word is not the first one, but that's not the point here." Okay, but that's what I do every time (really).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I change the structure of a sentence/add filler words to make sure that the sentence always starts with a capital letter?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21295/should-i-change-the-structure-of-a-sentence-add-filler-words-to-make-sure-that-th) and [Capitalization of names that begin lowercased, at the beginning of a sentence](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16027/capitalization-of-names-that-begin-lowercased-at-the-beginning-of-a-sentence).

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use *Word* or *Outlook*. They won't let you not capitalize the first word of a sentence. One more case of Microsoft encumbering the user with help.

Comment: @Robusto Oh, they will, they will. You'll just have to be persuasive enough. Large hammer almost always works :) On the point - in informal speech (IM with your friends) you can omit capitalizing letters at all. In more formal environment just rephrase you sentence, like Kosmonaut suggests.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Standard editorial practice is to recast the sentence so that the troublesome leading lowercased letter is pushed back, yes. That's how we handle the matter in my firm. However, occasionally tabular matter, listed items, etc., force an exception. Then you just have to grit your teeth and allow it.

Comment: @Rubusto: You can indeed override the default settings in Word/Outlook to permit an initial lowercased letter. It's under "Tools" / "Autocorrect Options" and is the second checkbox given.

Comment: @The Raven, and all auto-corrects can be undone immediately after they occur with lasting effect for the particular instance.

Comment: @Hui, you mean explicitly lowercase?

Answer (score 4):

If the word really demands lower case and you really really don't want to paraphrase to stop it looking odd, then you're left with keeping it in lower case and it looking slightly odd...

Answer (score 3):

No, you shouldn't capitalize. I think you are referring to the rule that proper nouns should always be capitalized, but there are many examples where they are not, for e.g., *iTunes, iPod, pH(from chemistry)* They are never capitalized.

Comment: Although I think that `pH` would never start a sentence... But, then again, I might be wrong.

Comment: `pH` might start a sentence.