# Title Capitalization of Keywords in Programming Languages

Tags: capitalization, programming, titles, sentence-starts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capitalising a sentence whose first word is explicitly lowercase](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28383/capitalising-a-sentence-whose-first-word-is-explicitly-lowercase)
>   [Should I change the structure of a sentence/add filler words to make sure that the sentence always starts with a capital letter?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21295/should-i-change-the-structure-of-a-sentence-add-filler-words-to-make-sure-that-t)

In programming language documentation, it is common for keywords to appear in titles. Assuming that the keyword is strictly lowercase in the language, how should that keyword be capitalized if it is used as the first word in a title?

For example:

**int**
`int` is used to specify an integer type.

-- or --

**Int**
`int` is used to specify an integer type.

Comment: I think you would follow the same rule as outlined in the question ["How do you capitalize a proper noun such as iPhone."](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9063/how-do-you-capitalize-a-proper-noun-such-as-iphone)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should ***not*** be capitalized. If you're trying to make your documentation useful, don't introduce unnecessary complexities.

Use the lowercase **int** (in fact, use it in a different font, preferably monospaced) for the titles. And comment on the fact that it's lowercase, the first few times you use it, and explain **why** you're using it.

If you're writing about [Unix](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/routledge/unixlanguage.pdf) or any dialect of C, your readers may often need orientation to the types of text conventions involved in programming, in contrast to the types involved in more ordinary writing.

Comment: +1. *Dive into Python* uses lower-cased keywords in a medium fixed-width font, even though its headings are in all-caps with a black proportional font. It clashes a bit, sure – but it doesn't draw the stares that an upper-cased `int` would.

Comment: Many years ago I had to take over a software project full of references to **int** where the original programmer took it for granted that every such variable occupied two bytes of storage (it was *many* years!). I did a quick global *search and replace* changing them all to **Int**, which I #define'd as **short**. Gradually over the next couple of years maintenance I'd spend the odd few spare minutes checking some instances of **Int** in detail and deciding whether they should be **int** or **short**. I rather like that C++ is case-sensitive!