# Should a mathematical variable at the beginning of a sentence be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, mathematics, sentence-starts

If a sentence starts with a mathematical variable which normally is lower case, should that variable be capitalized? Or is it better to just avoid starting sentences with variables?

> 1. *x* and *y* represent the width and height of the anticuboctahedron.
> 2. *X* and *y* represent the width and height of the anticuboctahedron.
> 3. The width and height of the anticuboctahedron are represented by *x* and *y*.

Comment: X and x can represent different variables. They **mustn't** be confused.

Comment: My answer as a mathematician: The variable names should never be capitalised, *x* and *X* can very well be different variables. And variables at the beginning of a sentence should usually be avoided in writing.

I wanted to add that something else that should be avoided are consecutive formulas without words or at least punctuation between them, but then I could not come up with an example, it seems to be more of a problem in German than in English.

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate of that question. Here's the answer I was prevented from posting: "Note that *x* in a mathematical equation is not a word; it's not really even a letter. It's a **symbol**. As such, it's not subject to the normal rules of orthography.

As Edwin Ashworth noted in a comment, *x* must not be confused with *X*, which could represent something else: *X* is a different symbol from *x*.

If you need to start a sentence with *x*, do that. Don't capitalise it."

Comment: This has been asked many times before. I find it a bit hard to pick one question, though. Especially since most of those questions are closed as duplicates themselves. Perhaps some merging is in order.

Comment: @Andrew Be my guest and pick any of these instead: [1](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/54745/), [2](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/21295/), [3](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/57894/).

Comment: @Reg None of those explicitly deals with symbols, although [4](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/57894/) comes closest. But it's not a **very** good match.

Comment: As far as the English language is concerned, a computer keyword is as good a symbol as a mathematical variable. I am not seeing a fundamental difference between "*x* and *y* represent the width and height of the anticuboctahedron" and "*for* and *while* are used to specify loops".