# Capitalising the t in Twitter / twitter

Tags: capitalization, brands

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Should Trademarks be Written?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2903/how-should-trademarks-be-written)
>   [How do you capitalize a proper noun such as “iPhone”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9063/how-do-you-capitalize-a-proper-noun-such-as-iphone)

I'm writing a paper about the function of twitter as a news medium and I'm wondering about the capitalisation of the brand name. Normally one would start brand names with a capital letter, but the twitter logo made me doubt - it's such an explicitly lowercase t.

Internet companies or standards often use quite *refreshing* capitalisations in their brand names (WordPress, jQuery), and I was just wondering what your verdict was on 'twitter'. Should it be a capital T since it's a company name?

The twitter website does not seem to provide much confirmation in either direction, as it seems like the differen authors (i.e. on the blog) tend to go by different rules.

And what about words like *Tweet*, *Retweet* and *Mention*?

Comment: Have you looked at https://twitter.com? Every instance of the name, including the HTTPS certificate holder which Firefox displays, has a capital letter.

Comment: Related: [How should trademarks be written](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2903/how-should-trademarks-be-written), [How do you capitalize a proper noun such as iPhone](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9063/how-do-you-capitalize-a-proper-noun-such-as-iphone)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd capitalise it. If you don't, it could be mistaken for the verb. I see less risk of confusion by not capitalising *tweet*, *retweet* and *mention*.